# Wordpress blog fails to open

Tags: wp-admin, errors, user-access

When I try to view/access my blog I get the following message....

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas as to the cause and the solution?

> Warning: require(/home/photogian/room2850.com/wp-includes/post-template.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/photogian/room2850.com/wp-settings.php on line 119
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/photogian/room2850.com/wp-includes/post-template.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/photogian/room2850.com/wp-settings.php on line 119

Comment: Try [our search engine](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Permission+denied%22).

Comment: check file permission

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'll get those kinds of results because you have file permissions issues. The files all need to be readable and executable by whatever user the WordPress installation is running as (e.g. on most typical webservers, including if you're running LAMP/MAMP locally, it's usually something like the `www` user and `staff` group). You'll need to check the permissions and set them correctly. If you're on a Linux or Unix (including Mac) setup you can use a combination of `chown` and `chmod` to set the permissions correctly:

In the root directory of your WordPress install, you'll need to run something *like* (though not necessarily exactly this; it depends on your setup):

```
$ chown -R www:staff *
$ chmod -R 755 *
```

I believe you may also need to repeat those commands thus:

```
$ chown -R www:staff .*
$ chmod -R 755 .*
```

This way you'll catch some of the hidden files (e.g. the `.htaccess` file).

Also, you may need root permissions to do this, in which case you'd need to run those thus:

```
$ sudo chown -R www:staff *
$ sudo chown -R www:staff .*
$ sudo chmod -R 755 *
$ sudo chmod -R 755 .*
```

If you're using a GUI administration tool (like MAMP Pro, for example), you'll often find a **Permissions** setting somewhere there. In MAMP Pro, you can set all the permissions in a directory to be what they should using the **Permissions** button on the *General* tab in the *Hosts* area. There are likely similar settings in any XAMPP or Linux administration GUI.